# create css badge with pseudo-element only

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have an element with a known ID I can target. How could I create a bestseller-badge like this with css only? I cannot change the html.

[image]

I know how to create this but only if I could edit the html, which I cannot:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px; height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  background: #EEE;
}
.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px; top: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75px; height: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}
.ribbon span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: #79A70A;
  background: linear-gradient(#9BC90D 0%, #79A70A 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px; right: -21px;
}
.ribbon span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid #79A70A;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #79A70A;
}
.ribbon span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid #79A70A;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #79A70A;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <div class="ribbon"><span>Bestseller</span></div>
</div>
```

The thing is I only have the parent box and not the ribbon inside. I cant input html.

Comment: The snippet shows exactly what you want. I suppose the HTML you wrote isn't exactly what you have, but what you would have done? What do you actually have access?

Comment: Please show your HTML, even if we can't edit it we need to know what structure exists to help you effectively.

Comment: I was looking for some code for a new product badge, your html/css has helped me figure mine out. :) +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in pseudo elements you can't put any html markup, you need to get clever with just using simple shapes and combining them together. Additionally, you can't have multiple `:after` pseudo elements, so we are limited to just two shapes (one for `:after` and one for `:before`). The one in `:after` could be the bestseller front of the badge, with text. The trickiest part was to get the `clip-path: polygon(...points)` to get right so that we get the effect of trimmed ribbon. Fortunately, Firefox dev tools have a nifty polygon modification tool that was very helpful. Getting the two little corners that make the "wrap around" effect was a bit trickier, but putting it in a `:before` pseudo element with `z-index: -1` and a little hand-tweaked offset did the trick. The end effect is below:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px; height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  background: #EEE;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.bestseller:before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  width: 120px;
  display: block; 
  background: #79A70A;
  background: linear-gradient(#9BC90D 0%, #79A70A 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  right: -16px;
  clip-path: polygon(120px 20px, 90px -10px, 30px -10px, 0px 20px, 10px 30px,  110px 30px);
  height: 20px;
  width: 120px;
}
.bestseller:after {
  content: "bestseller";
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 120px;
  display: block; 
  background: #79A70A;
  background: linear-gradient(#9BC90D 0%, #79A70A 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px; right: -30px;
  clip-path: polygon(120px 20px, 90px -10px, 30px -10px, 0px 20px, 10px 30px,  110px 30px)
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box bestseller">
</div>
```

Comment: this is awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of only CSS using pseudo class, we cannot create exactly the same but similar to that is possible. Add the id "ribbon" to div with class "box" and try with the below css. Increment/decrement the height, top right, etc based on the size of your div.

```
#ribbon:before {
    content: "";
    width: 60px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    right: -28px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid green;
    height: 0;
}

#ribbon:after {
    content: "Bestseller";
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 60px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    right: 2px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Instead of trying with border for the background color of ribbon, you can also try using an ribbon image as background and use the text on top of it.

Comment: Would be nice with a snippet